# vandermonde matrix matlab confusion

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I'm trying to construct a [vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) using matlab.

My input vector is

```
t = [ 1 2 3 4 ]'
```

My output using the [vander function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vander.html) is:

```
ans =

 1     1     1     1
 8     4     2     1
27     9     3     1
64    16     4     1
```

Now if I'm not mistaken the vandermonde matrix of the vector in question should be:

```
1 1 1 1
1 2 4 8
1 3 9 27
1 4 16 64
```

now I just realized that I can achieve my desired result using something like:

```
>> fliplr(vander(t))

 ans =

 1     1     1     1
 1     2     4     8
 1     3     9    27
 1     4    16    64
```

Thanks.

Comment: The order of the columns in the Vandermonde matrix affects only one thing - the order of the polynomial coefficients in a resulting model that might be built. Once can use either form and be happy, as long as you know what comes out, and how to interpret it.

Comment: Just as a general tip: looks like you can create it an order of magnitude faster than `vander` by using `bsxfun(@power, t, 0:numel(t)-1);` (or if you prefer, `bsxfun(@power, t, numel(t)-1:-1:0);`).

Comment: Copy-pasting the contents of `vander` in-place is even faster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just flip the matrix (left/right) to get the one you want.

Comment: I don't think transposing would work since `transpose(vander(t))` would be [1 8 27 64; 1 4 9 16; 1 2 3 4; 1 1 1 1]

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia and Mathworld agree with you. However, [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vander.html) says that:

> A = vander(v) returns the Vandermonde matrix whose columns are powers
>   of the vector v, that is, A(i,j) = v(i)^(n-j), where n = length(v).

I have no idea why The Mathworks did it like this. You can use `fliplr` to achieve desired result.

Comment: TMW did it because they wanted the order of the coefficients to be decreasing, in tools like polyfit and polyval. This makes all of their tools consistent that use polynomials and piecewise polynomials (spline, pchip, etc.) Why someone did it in that order first is interesting, but one would probably need to ask either Cleve or Carl directly to get their input, as surely they were the culprits. I'm wondering if it might have to do with column permutations done in the solve, but that is only a wild guess.